# The JSON value could not be converted to Scraper.items[]

Tags: c#, json, object, web-scraping, system.text.json

so I am trying to convert a JSON string to a list of objects that I made myself but for some reasons it keeps throwing me errors and after googling it I couldn't find my error.

Here is what throws the error. (I already tried using a list instead of an array and it still made an exception).

```
items[] items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<items[]>(h.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
"The JSON value could not be converted to Scraper.items[]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
```

Here is what my object item looks like looks like :

```
    public Int64 id;
    public string title;
    public double price;
    public string currency;
    public string brand_title;
    public string size_title;
    public user user;
    public bool is_for_swap;
    public string url;
    public bool promoted;
    public photo photo;
    public int favorit_count;
    public bool is_favorite;
    public string badge;
    public string[] conversion;
    public int view_count;
```

(I know I am not doing propreties or any constructor. I deleted them all while trying to solve my issue. (Other objects are also there but I wont show them since I don't think they are the thing making my exceptions and I don't want this post to be unreadable))

My JSON : https://pastebin.com/AZE1AwhL

Thanks for reading this and getting some help would make me progress a lot on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you have linked is not an array. It's an object, with a property `items` which is an array. So `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<items[]>` won't work. You need to deserialize to a class with an `items` property.

Something like this:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

// ...

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true };
var wrapper = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Wrapper>(
    h.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
    options);

wrapper.Items // This is your array
```

Side note: C# naming conventions dictate you should use PascalCasing for class names. So `items` should be called `Items` or more apropriately `Item` since it's not a list type.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried it but for some reasons the array wrapper.Items is null.
Also, I wasn't using the PascalCasing because I was thinking I had to put the exact JSON key values so it would work.

Comment: @D.7 Ah, right. I updated the answer. By default the serializer ignore fields. Your `Item` class uses fields and not properties (normally you'd use properties in C#, so I'd recommend actually changing it to properties instead). Note also, that some of your fields have incorrect types, like `price` is actually a `string`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it works now. Was kinda my fault since I deleted my propreties for public attributes. Works perfect now. Thanks for your help